# Using Swift protocols extensions instead of static funcs

Tags: swift, protocols, extension-methods, static-methods

I have begun to see protocols and their extensions being used *solely* to hold general purpose functions. These funcs only use global symbols or input parameters. The code could be contained in static funcs on a concrete type. The protocols have no requirements or constraints except the funcs they provide in extensions. They have no associated types.

Example:

```swift
protocol Naming {
    func fetchName() -> String
}

extension Naming {
    func fetchName() -> String {
        // The exact code does not matter.
        // It calls some global object or maybe there are parameters.
        // The point is, all the code could be in a static func under a concrete type.
        return NotificationCenter.default.description
    }
}
```

To use this a type would have to conform to use the func and then call the func on `self`. Like this:

```swift
class Road: Naming {
    func logName() {
        print(fetchName())
    }
}
```

By analogy, imagine if Swift Standard Library `Int.random(in:)` could not be called unless your type conformed to `Int`.

Typically, such a function would be a static func on a concrete type. Sometimes that concrete type is merely a name space. Like this:

```swift
struct Name {
    static func fetchName() -> String {
        return NotificationCenter.default.description
    }
}
```

It would be used like this:

```swift
class Street {
    func logName() {
        print(Name.fetchName())
    }
}
```

My question is, what are the advantages and drawbacks to using this technique?

Some disadvantages that I see:

1. Too many protocols and too much protocol conformance and boilerplate code.

   - It seems excessive to have a type conform to a protocol just to get access to what could be a global func.
2. It forces inheritance when composition will suffice.
3. Worse performance because of dynamic dispatch.

I do not see any advantages.

Comment: I don’t see any point in doing this

Comment: Yeah, sounds weird. Also, though, I've never seen this in the wild. Perhaps you want to discuss this with whoever has written the code?

Comment: @RobNapier I have and my reasoning was rebuffed. That's why I wrote this question: to get authoritative reasoning on this exact topic. I realize we cannot document everything you are *not* supposed to do, but this seems like it could become a legit anti-pattern. Thus, the need to publicly document it.

Comment: BTW, in your `struct Name` example, generally if you want a namespace, you'd use an enum with no cases. The main thing I see as a mistake in the protocol code is that it defines a requirement rather than just the extension. It shouldn't do that unless it really means for conforming types to override it (I don't think pure extension functions require dynamic dispatch, since they can't be overridden, but the bigger reason is to make it clear it can't be overridden). I don't know that this is a complete anti-pattern. It kind of depends on how it's being used.

Comment: Your specific example is definitely weird (and I know it's just a simplified example). As a mix-in, though, it might be fine. It would depend on what it's trying to express. Conformance is not inheritance; it is a type of composition. So this feels more a question of what is being expressed, and whether it expresses that reasonably. I'd definitely call this an opinion question.

Comment: @RobNapier if there are valid technical reasons to do this and aspects to consider, then those reasons and aspects are the answer to this question. Asking for items to consider when choosing which technique to use is not an open discussion type of question as prohibited by the rules, imo. Now, if I asked about a particular case and asked if my conclusion from the guidelines were good, that is an opinion question. I am asking for what criteria to consider (technical expertise). I am not asking for validation of my conclusion from those criteria (opinion).

Comment: OK; I have no technical input to give here other than I don't believe this would actually create dynamic dispatch if the protocol requirement were removed, and it feels like it would be fine to do that in this pattern.